# Toilet keeps running!

Tags: toilet

If I leave the refill hose in the Overflow tube it keeps running.  But if I just put the refill hose in the tank it fills to the place I have it set at and stops.  Is this a problem.  The guy at Home Depot says yes but he told me to just replace the toilet.  Really I said.  It is not the trap because why would it fill at all if it was that.  I think it is something in the overflow tube.  But do I have to change it.

Comment: Is the tank filling up in both circumstances?

Comment: Yes it is.  I don't think it is a problem.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, so to that point, if the tank is fully filling at what seems to be the normal rate, and the tube is still running nonstop, then @JimmyFix-it is got it. Either answer below could have been the culprit given the lack of initial info. Thanks for follow up

Answer (score 2):

If the refill hose is placed into the overflow tube (as opposed to clipped above it, as it should be), it could cause a siphon issue resulting in a continuous lowering of the tank water level.

This would normally cause the toilet fill valve to cycle on *intermittently* (to fill the tank when the level drops low enough to actuate the fill valve float mechanism), as opposed to continuously (you wrote "keeps running"). However, the "running" noise you are hearing might be the sound of the siphoning process itself. [video explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZnsS8Vb12aI)

This phenomenon is well known and can happen with most any fill valve (I won't say **all** because I just don't know). Your fill valve should have been equipped with a clip or tube guide to hold the refill hose above the overflow tube or to hold it just inside but not lower than the tank water level.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the line to the tank fill is plugged and the tank is not getting water flow, time to clean the valve or replace just the valve since it works with the tube in the tank. Turn the water off remove the top of the valve put a cup over the top of the valve. Turn the water on let it flush the valve and turn off. Put the top of the valve back on turn water on and see if the tank fills, if it fills problem solved if it still won't fill the tank replace the valve, flowmaster valves are less than 20$ at most big box stores and very easy to swap out.

Comment: The other possibility is that the flapper is not seating fully, so the rinse water + tank fill =  flow fast enough to fill the tank that it "stops" running (perception). Or to your point, tank fill is just filling so slowly, it "appears" to be running too long.

Comment: Did I miss something? Did the OP say that the tank was not filling? That would, of course, be a horse of a different color.

Comment: Agreed @noybman +. a leak could make it take longer to fill and it may not seal until more water pressure is on the flapper.